# Are flags still reviewed if the post is deleted?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-answers

I [downvoted this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131020/error-pops-up-after-clicking-button/28131171#28131171) (only 10k+ can view) that was a simple copy-paste of a portion of the official documentation (with one sentence of the user's own).

I also flagged the answer as it did not even attribute the official MSDN documentation or link to the content with an `Other` flag as there is no flag option for flagging a question which does not attribute the original source.
I submitted an edit to the post shortly before it was removed and the OP of the answer edited their question, one minute later the question was removed (probably by the author).

I've gone into my flag history and see this:

[image]

the moderator flag I cast is still active.

If a flagged post is deleted before the flag is seen to, will the flag still be seen by the applicable user(s)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, any active flag will still show to moderators whether the post is deleted or not. Custom flags can sometimes contain information that warrants further moderator action than *just* post deletion, so they do not ever get automatically cleared with a non-moderator post deletion.

Comment: Does this include standard flags such as duplicate flags and NAA? Would've thought those flags would be automatically marked as 'helpful' or 'disputed' and dismissed.

Comment: @cybermonkey Only custom flags are kept. Anything else gets automatically cleared.

Comment: @animuson: Does that mean I could just delete and undelete my post to clear nearly all pending flags? Or will they get re-instated on undeletion (Which I sincerely hope)?

Comment: @Deduplicator You can. They would all get marked as helpful upon deletion. But it's not very beneficial for you if any of them were VLQ flags, as they carry an implicit downvote when they get marked helpful. So you'd only be dropping your score. If it truly should be deleted, it's gonna get flagged again in the future anyways.